# Fill a MDF Database with CSV data

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well this is how my CSV data looks like:

```
Artistname;RecordTitle;RecordType;Year;SongTitle
999;Concrete;LP;1981;Mercy Mercy
999;Concrete;LP;1981;Public Enemy No.1
999;Concrete;LP;1981;So Greedy
999;Concrete;LP;1981;Taboo
10cc;Bloody Tourists;LP;1978;Dreadlock Holiday
10cc;Bloody Tourists;LP;1978;Everyhing You've Ever Wanted To Know About!!!
10cc;Bloody Tourists;LP;1978;Shock On The Tube
```

This is my code where I save this data in the Database:

```
 private void FillDatabase()
    {
        
        var firstTime = true;
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("musicDbData.csv");
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var split = line.Split(";");
            if (!firstTime)
            {
                var artist = new Artist()
                {
                    ArtistName = split[0],
                };
                db.Artists.Add(artist);
               db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                firstTime = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that every artist should be in the Database only once. Right now there is 4 times Artist 999 and 3 times 10cc and if everything is correct there should only be one row for 999 and one row for 10cc. What do I have to add to my code to get the expected result.

Comment: Did you try HashSet?

Comment: You have to start be modelling your database. My suggestion is to use three tables: One table for the artists, one table for the records and one table for the songs. In the song-table, use a FK to the records, and in the records-table, use a FK to the artists.

Comment: @Xaver that was not my question mate

Comment: @raj_345: You wrote: "The problem is that every artist should be in the Database only once." You can only achieve this if you model your database accordingly. You have to store the artists in a different table than the rest of the data. My comment is absolutely related to your question!

Comment: It should have been your question. You are not modelling this properly. You need to add each `Artist` to a `Dictionary` or `Hashset` by checking you have not seen that one before in the dictionary. If you have then you can create a `Song` to add to that `Artist`

Answer (score 0):

First, a CSV is a comma-separated values file, rather than semicolon.

Besides, the parameter in method `String.Split` can be type of `Char`. So you need to modify it like `line.Split(';')`.

And your csv file contains column name line, you need to exclude it when reading the file.

> if everything is correct there should only be one row for 999 and one row for 10cc

Do you want to just save the first data of 999 and 10cc to the database? If so, you can first use LINQ to check whether the Artistname already exists in the database.

```
private void FillDatabase()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("musicDbData.csv");
    int count = 0; // line count

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 1) // remove first line
            continue;

        var split = line.Split(';');
        string artistname = split[0];

        var artistIndb = db.ArtistTables
        .Where(c => c.Artistname == artistname)
        .SingleOrDefault();

        if (artistIndb == null) // check if exists, if not ...
        {
            var artist = new ArtistTable()
            {
                Artistname = split[0],
                SongTitle = split[4]
            };
            db.ArtistTables.Add(artist);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to merge lines with the same Artistname, you can refer to the following code.

```
if (artistIndb == null)
{
    // code omitted
    // ...
}
else
{
    artistIndb.SongTitle += " ," + split[4]; // Modify the data in SongTitle column
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch { }
}
```